# List only repeating names

Tags: sql, sqlite, rdbms

```
| personid | first | last | section |
| 1        | Jon   | A    | y3      |
| 2        | Bob   | Z    | t6      |
| 3        | Pat   | G    | h4      |
| 4        | Ron   | Z    | u3      |
| 5        | Sam   | D    | y3      |
| 6        | Sam   | D    | u3      |
| 7        | Pam   | F    | h4      |
```

I want to isolate all the repeat names, despite the other columns, like this:

```
| personid | first | last | section |
| 5        | Sam   | D    | y3      |
| 6        | Sam   | D    | u3      |
```

This is what I came up with but I cannot get it to work:

```
SELECT personid, last, first, section FROM   d 01 WHERE  EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM d 02 WHERE  02.last = 01.last AND 02.first = 01.first )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check that the 2 rows have different ids:

```
SELECT d1.personid, d1.last, d1.first, d1.section 
FROM d d1 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM d d2 
  WHERE d1.personid <> d2.personid AND d2.last = d1.last AND d2.first = d1.first 
)
```

Always qualify the column names with the table's name/alias and don't use numbers as aliases unless they are enclosed in backticks or square brackets.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2F9EyH9ibGBq9zPa4GaHVn/0).
Results:

```
| personid | last | first | section |
| -------- | ---- | ----- | ------- |
| 5        | D    | Sam   | y3      |
| 6        | D    | Sam   | u3      |
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes total sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a window count and filter by that:

```
select personid, first, last, section
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by first, last) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to yield the same results as the other accepted answer:

```
SELECT personid,
   A.firstName,
   A.lastName,
   section
FROM personTable as A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  
        firstName,
        lastName,
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'Null' , AS UseName
    FROM 
        personTable
    WHERE UseName='Yes') as B 
 ON A.firstName=B.firstName AND A.lastName=B.lastName
```

This solution subqueries itself. Since it is an inner join, it will only pull the values that join onto the subquery. Since I filtered anything with a count less than 2 out, only the duplicates will match.